# Make MainMenu.xib respect system region

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization

How can I make MainMenu.xib localization respect system region. For ex: Let's say the system language is set to English (generic i.e. en) and system region is set to United Kingdom then MainMenu for my application should reflect English (U.K) strings and not English (generic) strings.